# JMeter plugin: Test plan checker failed to detect cmdrunner-2.2.jar on Windows

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying JMeter [Test plan checker tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TestPlanCheckTool/) on my Windows setup, but I get the following error -

```
.\TestPlanCheck.bat --jmx <test_plan>

Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\<...path>\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext\\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar
```

I've C:<...path>\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar in place.

I tried with following versions of the tool - 2.4 and 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to wrong path at with TestPlanChecker was present in my system. I unzipped it in <JMETER_HOME>/lib/ext folder after downloading. While the tool needs to be in the JMeter bin folder for successful execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead running it like this from folder containing the jmeter folder:

> apache-jmeter-5.3/lib/ext/TestPlanCheck.sh --jmx TestPlan.jmx

Comment: why do you have 2 levels of apache-jmeter-5.3 ?

Comment: That's just from the unzip of apache jmeter package.